# JS - Lodash; Nested Objects (parents/children) to flat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects, lodash

I am using lodash (although solution doesn't have to) and I want to convert the following structure:

```
{ prop1: 'root',
  prop2: 'someVal',
  children: [
    { prop1: 'first Child',
      prop2: 'some other val',
      children: [
        { prop1: 'last child'
          prop2: 'another value'
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

to a flat array:

```
[ { prop1: 'root', prop2: 'someVal' }, 
  {prop1: 'firstChild', prop2: 'some Other Val'}, 
  {prop1: 'last child', prop2: 'another value'}
]
```

The depth can vary, and the last child will always have `[]` assigned to its `children` property; Note that in that particular case, the children array will always have a single item in it

Should be fairly straightforward but it seems I just can't put the finger on it for some reasons

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this snippet (in CoffeeScript)

```
flatten = (node) ->
        row = node
        _.each node.children or [], (el) ->
            flatten el
        ancestors.push row
```

Comment: and where is `ancestors` defined?

Answer (score 1):

This is for using an *anonymous target* to flatten into (e.g. `flattened`)

```
flatten = (collection, flattened = [])->
  _.each collection, (obj)->
    flattened.push obj
    flatten obj.children, flattened
  flattened
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using pure JS:-
http://jsbin.com/bazilurolu/edit?js,console

```
var flatArray = function(input){
    var result = [];
    (function(obj){
        var arr = [], newObj = {};
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if(key !== "children"){
                    newObj[key] = obj[key];
                }
                else{
                    arr = obj[key];
                }
            }
        }
        result.push(newObj);
        if(arr.length){
            arguments.callee(arr[0]);
        }
    })(input);
    return result;
};
```

Comment: In "strict mode", arguments.callee is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Typescript version of the solution of @jusopi

```js
const flatten = (collection: any[], flattened?: any[]) => {
    if (!flattened) {
        flattened = [];
    }
    _.each(collection, (obj) => {
        flattened!.push(obj);
        flatten(obj.children, flattened);
    });
    return flattened;
};
```